# Mvc: The use of IQueryable and Asqueryable is not clear

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I found some lines of code online and I understand the first two lines. Data of a particular
type is cached and stored in the two properties of the models below.

```
model.payment = (List<CompInfor>)HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey + "_received"];
model.FilteredPayment = (List<CompInfor>)HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey + "_received"];
```

However I don't understand the line below as I have never written code like this below.
Please what does this line do? What does it mean? I know you can save a lot of resources by using IQueryable.

```
IQueryable<CompInfor> payment = model.FilteredPayment.AsQueryable<CompInfor>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply returns an instance of the `IQueryable<T>` [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) which will utilize a query provider to act upon the object in question (in your case, the `model.FilteredPayment` list).  It doesn't seem to make much sense when you're acting against a `List` locally, but (as an example) in the case of entity framework where you build query statement to be executed against a database via SQL, the Linq to Entities query provider processes the `IQueryable` into the appropriate SQL statement for execution against the database and processes the results.